# What does "imageable" mean in the rails docs explaining polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, associations

So, I am trying to implement a polymorphic association and [reviewing the Rails Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), but am a but confused how they are using "imageable." Is "imageable" some sort of convention or should it really be tied to a table called "imageable"?

Comment: Heya, did you get it working? If so - did my answer help? If so - it's generally Good Form to "accept" the answer. you can do that by hovering your mouse over the answer... a "tick" mark appears on the left. Click that tick so it goes green and you have accepted the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`imageable` is an unwritten naming-convention in Rails polymorphic associations.

Another example is `taggable` - which refers to an object that can be tagged ie, that is `taggable`. Or for the `imageable` example, the object that has an attached image is `imageable` because it can accept an image.

In this case, you'd have columns on the `belongs_to` object (`Picture`) called `imageable_id` and `imageable_type` storing the id and model-class of the associated object. You don't need an `imageable` table... just the columns on the `Picture` model

Comment: I know this is an old post, but does the column have to be named `imageable` or can you do anything, such as `randomable`?

Comment: It can be named other things - it's quite common to name it with whatever is appropriate for your circumstances :)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the response!!